# Objective-C - Base64 string to base64Binary (XML)

Tags: objective-c, xml, soap, base64

I'm developing an app on iOS requesting a web service with SOAP, and I have an issue with the datatype *xsd:base64Binary* (XML).

I build my SOAP envelope according to the expected fields from the web service. When the types are *xsd:string* or *xsd:integer* or any other simple type, I have no problem.
But when I try to add an *xsd:base64Binary* type to the SOAP envelope, the web service cannot receive the data correctly; it seems to be an encoding issue but I can't figure it out.

For example, the envelope looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- to instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <hereTheMethod xmlns="http://heretheaddress/">
      <aBase64>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...
              ...RRQAUUUUAf/Z</aBase64>
      <aBool>false</aBool>
      <anInt>89</anInt>
      <aDouble>0.0</aDouble>
      <aString>Hello</aString>
    </hereTheMethod>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Then the web service reads "false", "89", "0.0" or "Hello" without any problem. But with base64, I have something like "����JFIF��XExifMM*�i&..." as an encoding problem.

In Objective-C, I proceed like :

```
NSMutableString *envelopeText = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"(header)\n"
    "<aBase64>%@</aBase64>\n"
    "(footer)", base64String];

// Some code...

NSData *envelope = [envelopeText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// I launch the connection.
```

Lastly, when I build the base64 string, I take care to encode it in UTF-8 like :

```
NSString *base64String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Notice that the app also exists for Android (Java), and works with the same web service correctly.

Thanks for your help !

PS : Sorry for my English :/

Answer (score 1):

try use CDATA for Base64 string like this:

```
<aBase64><![CDATA[%@]]></aBase64>\n
```

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-cdata/), to use CDATA was a good idea, and yet it doesn't work; The web service receives exactly the same string than before :/
But thanks you for your answer.

Comment: you're most welcome... but can you just tell me what exact error you are having??

Comment: i have the same thing that you have in your code and its working fine.

Comment: The string receive by the web service isn't valid : as I wrote, when sending a string like "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...RRQAUUUUAf/Z" in a tag _base64binary_, the string retrieved by the web service is "����JFIF��XExifMM*�i&..." and not the expected "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...RRQAUUUUAf/Z". I hope I'm clear enough, it's hard to explain more precisely since I'm not the one who created the web service.

Comment: okk i understand but i don't know what is the exact problem here? may you can change the web method arguments.give just one argument for XML and give all info like aBool, aBase64 in one XML string and send that XML as argument using CDATA. may that should do the trick.

Comment: You means to send only one _xsd:string_ to the web service ? Of course it will works, even with several tags, the problem is that only the _xsd:base64binary_ tag doesn't work... Or I misunderstood you ?

Comment: i mean remove all arguments from web service and add just one argument  of string type. now in that argument send XML string which includes all the information you required including base64 string as well. and see if you are getting your data in web service correctly.

Comment: In this case no problem, the web service receives correctly the string "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAB...RRQAUUUUAf/Z false 89 0.0 Hello". But what if I have to use an XML base64binary type ?

Comment: can't you convert string to base64binary type??

Comment: No, the string is immediatly unrecognized. I have totally no idea of what is going wrong. If I send "0000" (00110000 00110000 00110000 00110000), the web service get "ÓM4" (11000011 10010011 01001101 00110100) (in UTF-8).

Comment: Finally I had the right to get the web service changed. The base64 string is now of type _xsd:string_ instead of _xsd:base64binary_. The problem remains unsolved, but at least, it works ! Thanks for your help.